# Dynamically inserting javascript with Jquery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I'm trying to append on body's HTML js librarys with JQuery, because I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/ChatJs/Scripts/jquery.zambachat.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
   <script src="/Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/ChatJs/Scripts/jquery.chatjs.signalradapter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script src="/ChatJs/Scripts/jquery.autosize.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/ChatJs/Scripts/jquery.activity-indicator-1.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>       
    <script src="/ChatJs/Scripts/jquery.chatjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script src="/Scripts/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>  
    </head>

</html>
```

And I want only have this:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>    
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/ChatJs/Scripts/jquery.zambachat.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </head>    
    </html>
```

I'm putin the reference of JS in "jquery.zambachat.js"
I tried with all code that I seen in internet. I have this code, in this file for each JS.
 I try to append but dont work.

```
(function ($) {
  $.getScript("/Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js", function () {
        alert("Running js");
    });
  var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "C:\Users\starerdoc\Desktop\ZamreaChat\Samples\ChatJsMvcSample\ChatJs\Scripts\Bootstrap\js\bootstrap.min.js";      
    $("head").append(s);
```

//and this code
        $('head').append('');
       })(jQuery);
If I try to append a style css like

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />');
```

Its work's ok, but not with JS. Im using Chrome 
Thanks.

Comment: Which js append that's not working?

Comment: `s.src = "C:\Users\...";` Are you trying to append local file? Error in console? Etc...

Comment: Both codes dont work like a function: "  $.getScript("/Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js", function () {}" and append with JQuery to HTML "$('head').append(JS FILE)"

Comment: A. Wolff: One error of the codes is it, the path of the script, how can i resolve this, maybe if I put correctly the path It work, thanks

Comment: @Javysk Ya, putting relevant path would help for sure. But are you running it using a server (local or not) or just trying to load some local files?

Comment: If I debbug with Chrome I have this error "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/*****"

Comment: In this moment Im debbuging in localhost, after this I will put in a server, this files are in the proyect in folder "ChatJS/Scripts"

Comment: Ya because, for security reason, chrome doesn't allow it by default. Run a local server to serve files (best choice) or set chrome to allow it: http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/  If you are already running a server, then you need to set script path relative to your server URL, not local path

Comment: An example of fisical path  s.src = "C:\Users\starerdoc\Desktop\ZamreaChat\Samples\ChatJsMvcSample\ChatJs\Scripts\Bootstrap\js\bootstrap.min.js";

Comment: Thaks, I will try to configure Chrome, This proyect is a Chat and I need this proyect works in Chrome, IE and Firefox, Will i need configure all browsers? Because a lot of clients will use this application. When i put this proyect in a server i wont need configure browsers? thanks

Comment: `When i put this proyect in a server i wont need configure browsers?` No you won't.  BUT better is to start running a local server for develepoment purpose and use relative URLs. This would avoid many headhaches once you will pass it to production server

Comment: Im  using windows, i do all the Chrome page says. Open command console CMD, and do "cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\" then "chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files" it open a new chrome but in this i have the same error, I try with ""C:/Users/" and this mode ""C:\Users\"

Comment: I don't know why you do not use a local server to avoid this kind of problems. Please take note of @A.Wolff's last comment. Install an AIO solution like WAMPP or XAMPP to develop in pre-production mode (this means that you can work like a real server, but in local, which means faster).